# Regex gives something wrong in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this piece of code:

```
if ($line =~ /gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:._]*)";/) {
            $chromosome{$1} = $chompline[0];
            push @{$starts{$1}}, $chompline[3];
            push @{$ends{$1}}, $chompline[4];
            $strand{$1} = $chompline[6];
            $geneid = $1;
            $line =~ /;transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:._]*)";/;
            $transcriptid = $1;
        }
```

This code reads the following file:

```
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    40478   40618   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    40723   40832   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    40944   41016   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    41667   41728   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    42268   42585   .   -   .   gene_id "ppa017353m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17642447";tss_id "TSS3451"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    43369   43510   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    44834   45052   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    45195   45261   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    47061   47460   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
scaffold_1  Cufflinks   exon    49006   49153   .   +   .   gene_id "ppa023343m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17657390";tss_id "TSS1"
```

and the code works well with all the rows except these ones:

```
scaffold_2  Cufflinks   exon    16897769    16898166    .   -   .   gene_id "ppa018337m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17646596_o.3";tss_id "TSS10299"
scaffold_2  Cufflinks   exon    16899376    16899536    .   -   .   gene_id "ppa018337m.g";transcript_id "PAC:17646596_o.3";tss_id "TSS10299"
```

For example, I want the following output:

```
ppa023343m.g PAC:17657390
```

And it happens all the time except for those lines I've shown to you... in case of those lines, I obtain the following result:

```
PAC:17646596_o.3 PAC:17646596
```

How is that possible?

Comment: The code you posted outputs nothing.

Comment: show more of your code; what generates the output?  what makes @chompline?

Comment: You may wish to know that `[A-Za-z0-9:._]` is the same as `[\w:.]`

Answer (score 1):

In your second regex, you are saying:

```
$line =~ /;transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:._]*)";/;
```

You are allowing characters from `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z` as well as all numbers, colon `:`, dot `.` and underscore `_`. Your lines have this stuff:

```
transcript_id "PAC:17646596_o.3";
transcript_id "PAC:17646596_o.3";
```

All the things in your character group from the regex are in there, so they match. There's the underscore and the dot, and more letters and numbers. Your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Maybe this explanation helps you understand it better: http://regex101.com/r/dE9hJ3

---

If you do not want the `_o.3` in your output, change the regex to his:

```
$line =~ /;transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:]*)[^"]*";/;
        #                               ^
        #             notice the ) here ends the capture group
```

Comment: the OP needs to check if the regex succeeds, not just use $1 blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Always verify that a regex succeeds before utilizing captured variables.

```
$transcriptid = $line =~ /;transcript_id "([\w:.]*)";/
    ? $1
    : warn "transcript_id didn't match: $line";
```

Alternatively, you can also join the regex matching into a single statement and therefore only have to error check once:

```
if ($line =~ /gene_id "([\w:.]*)";transcript_id "([\w:.]*)";/) {
    ($geneid, $transcriptid) = ($1, $2);

    $chromosome{$geneid} = $chompline[0];
    push @{$starts{$geneid}}, $chompline[3];
    push @{$ends{$geneid}}, $chompline[4];
    $strand{$geneid} = $chompline[6];

} else {
    warn "Regex didn't match: $line\n"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape characters like the period or it will match anything. Also, it makes much more sense to have a single regex capture both pieces of data (based on what code you posted and not knowing what your intentions are):

```
if ($line =~ /gene_id "([^\"]*)";transcript\_id\s\"(PAC:[^\"]*)\"/ ) {
    $geneid = $1;
    $transcriptid = $2;
}
```

EDIT: Link to regex demo: http://regex101.com/r/wK1gF8

Comment: There is no need to escape a dot `.` inside a character class.